# Mysql Said: #1325 Cursor is already open

Tags: mysql

I am getting error as cursor is already open, and if i fix an error, my loop executes infinite times

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_StatementOfAccont_Closingbal_new`(IN `Ac_code` BIGINT, IN `fdate` DATE, IN `tdate` DATE, IN `opening` DOUBLE, IN `dc` VARCHAR(25), IN `drsum` DOUBLE, IN `crsum` DOUBLE)
        NO SQL
Begin

    DECLARE cur_name1 CURSOR FOR select Ac_code from ledger_master;

    BEGIN
        OPEN cur_name1;
        MAIN_LOOP: LOOP         
            FETCH cur_name1 INTO Ac_code;     
            select @opening := Op_bal from ledger_master where Ac_code=Ac_code;             
            select @dc := op_dc from ledger_master where Ac_code=Ac_code;               
            select @drsum := sum(Amount) from ledgerentry where DC='dr' and Ac_code=Ac_code and  ledgerentry.date <= @tdate;                
            select @crsum := sum(Amount) from ledgerentry where DC='cr' and Ac_code=Ac_code and  ledgerentry.date <= @tdate;
            if (@dc='cr' and @opening>0) THEN
                set @opening := 0-@opening;
            END IF;
            set @opening := ifnull( @opening,0) + ifnull(@drsum,0) - ifnull(@crsum,0);

            delete from tmp_closingbalance;

            if(@opening>0) then
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code,@opening,0);
            ELSEIF(@opening<0) then
                set @opening := 0-@opening;
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code, 0,@opening );    
            ELSEIF(@opening=0) then
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code,0,0);    
            end if;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_name1;
    END;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the cursor uin the loop do it before that.

I also changed the code to include a finished Option, so that the loop don't run into NULLs

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_StatementOfAccont_Closingbal_new`(IN `Ac_code` BIGINT, IN `fdate` DATE, IN `tdate` DATE, IN `opening` DOUBLE, IN `dc` VARCHAR(25), IN `drsum` DOUBLE, IN `crsum` DOUBLE)
        NO SQL
Begin
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE cur_name1 CURSOR FOR select Ac_code from ledger_master;

    OPEN cur_name1;
    BEGIN

        MAIN_LOOP: LOOP         
            FETCH cur_name1 INTO Ac_code; 
            IF finished = 1 THEN 
                LEAVE MAIN_LOOP;
            END IF;
            select @opening := Op_bal from ledger_master where Ac_code=Ac_code;             
            select @dc := op_dc from ledger_master where Ac_code=Ac_code;               
            select @drsum := sum(Amount) from ledgerentry where DC='dr' and Ac_code=Ac_code and  ledgerentry.date <= @tdate;                
            select @crsum := sum(Amount) from ledgerentry where DC='cr' and Ac_code=Ac_code and  ledgerentry.date <= @tdate;
            if (@dc='cr' and @opening>0) THEN
                set @opening := 0-@opening;
            END IF;
            set @opening := ifnull( @opening,0) + ifnull(@drsum,0) - ifnull(@crsum,0);

            delete from tmp_closingbalance;

            if(@opening>0) then
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code,@opening,0);
            ELSEIF(@opening<0) then
                set @opening := 0-@opening;
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code, 0,@opening );    
            ELSEIF(@opening=0) then
                insert into tmp_closingbalance values(Ac_code,0,0);    
            end if;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur_name1;
    END;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I have tried it sir , but it gives #1337 - Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration

Comment: I edited my answer , sorry i added finished in an after some consioderation

Comment: Procedure created but on execution it shows  MySQL said: #1329 - No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
but database has so much entries..

Comment: that i can't test so test select Ac_code from ledger_master; in phpmyadmin and cheeck every query, but as i saif wirth any data nobody can test this but you

Comment: If i use code which is middle part of loop, and i pass parameter single Ac_code, it gives result for every Ac_code, but if i use loop and cursor , it shows zero data result.

Comment: You write a SET @a = Ac_code;  before the select @opening := and after calling the procedure make a SELECT @a; and see the result. If there is a result, you take SET @a and test all the variables and the comes the big if ifekse cinstruct checj which it takes,. Take nothing for granted, go methodically one step at a time.

Comment: I gone through step by step, syntax and right method to execute cursor and loop, and finally its done, thank you so much sir for helping me for this query. Actually i have completed this task in sql server 2005 & 8, but first time doing it in mysql. Thank You.
changed: 1. DECLARE exit_loop BOOLEAN; , 2. before open cursor, i added -> DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET exit_loop = TRUE; 3. before 1 step of end loop ->   IF exit_loop  THEN 
        CLOSE cur_name1;
        LEAVE MAIN_LOOP;
     END IF;
    
and Finally its done.